# Angular - update services object during asynchronous function

Tags: angularjs

Folks: Creating an app in angular and node webkit - where users queue up files for downloading, navigate to their dashboard view and this initiates the downloads.

I've created a service which holds an object of the files data:

```
  ..
  var downloadObj = {};
  // fileObj = {'name':'The file name'; 'download_progress' : dlProgress}

  showcaseFactory.myDownloads = function(eventId, fileObj) {
    if(eventId){
      console.log('update the object');
      downloadObj['event_'+eventId] = fileObj;
    }
    console.log(downloadObj);
  };

  showcaseFactory.getDownloads = function() {
    return downloadObj;
  };
..
```

When the dashboard view loads - `ng-repeat` loops over `$scope.downloadFiles` which references this object returning the data.

```
  <div ng-repeat="file in downloadFiles">
    <div><span>{{file.name}}</span> [{{file.download_progress}}%]</div>
  </div>
```

I've created a custom module which utilises `node_modules` to perform the download of the files:

```
nwjsDownloadFactory.commenceDownload = function(event_id, url, dest, cb) {
  var http = require('http');
  var fs = require('fs');
  var statusBar = require('status-bar');
  var path = require('path');

  // THIS UPDATES THE OBJECT AND DISPLAYS FINE --------- >>
  var id = 7;
  var testFileObj = {
    'name' : 'This is the file name prior to the download...',
    'download_progress' : 10
  };
  ShowCase.myDownloads(id, testFileObj);
  // <<< THIS UPDATES THE OBJECT AND DISPLAYS FINE ---------

  var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
  var request = http.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);

    file.on('finish', function() {
      file.close(cb);  // close() is async, call cb after close completes.
    });

    bar = statusBar.create({ total: response.headers['content-length'] })
    .on('render', function (stats) {

      // var percentage = this.format.percentage(stats.percentage);
      // console.log(event_id + '....' + percentage);

      var id = 7;
      var testFileObj = {
        'name' : 'This is the new file name during the download...',
        'download_progress' : 35 // this will be replaced with percentage
      };
      ShowCase.myDownloads(id, testFileObj);

    });
      response.pipe(bar);
    }).on('error', function(err) { // Handle errors
        fs.unlink(dest); // Delete the file async. (But we don't check the result)
        if (cb) cb(err.message);
      });

  }
```

**QUESTION**: Prior to the line `var request = http.get(url, function(response)` the object gets updated, and the changes are reflected in the UI.  However, I need to constantly update the object with download complete % so I can create a progress bar.. However, as this asynchronous function executes, the object 
**appears** to be updating - see the attached screen shot - but the UI is not reflecting this.

Can somebody please steer me in the right direction - I need the object to update during the function `bar = statusBar.create({` and for the changes to reflect in the UI..

[image: object is being updated - but changes not reflected in drop down]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `$scope.$apply()` after making changes to your model to notify Angular that it has to update the UI.

```
showcaseFactory.myDownloads = function(eventId, fileObj) {
  if(eventId){
    console.log('update the object');
    downloadObj['event_'+eventId] = fileObj;
    $scope.$apply();
  }
  console.log(downloadObj);
};
```

If you use Angular's `$http` object, this is handled automatically for you, but if you update your model from other asynchronous callbacks, you have to take care of it yourself.

See [this blog post](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html) and [this documentation page](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply%28%29) for more in-depth explanations about what's going on.

Comment: Thanks! Saved me bacon.. instead of $scope, I had to use $rootScope, because I couldn't inject $scope into the service - works well